# Tools used for ETL jobs

Tags: python, etl, aws-glue

Does anyone here write ETLs or ELTs in Python (purely Python - Not PySpark)? If yes, what are some of the gotchas of writing ETLs in Python? We are currently using SAP Data Services, but are wanting to move away from it and use AWS Glue, Lambda, Redshift etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Redshift is a powerful tool and can be used for ETL purposes for sure. Usually using regular Redshift SQL queries and tooling should handle the most of your cases.

For more advanced scenarios you can consider using Redshift with [Python UDF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html). Redshift comes with impressive set of libraries included out of the box (like Numpy or Pandas). Also you can easily import your own libraries into Redshift.